# .NET framework version for clients

Tags: .net, wpf, windows, installation

If I develop a WPF app in .NET Framework 4.7.2, do my clients need to have .NET 4.7.2 installed on their machine too?

I'm using WiX to create the .msi package if that's relevant

Comment: Short answer: yes. If you target .NET 4.7.2, the clients must install .NET 4.7.2 or later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's necessary to install the .NET Framework 4.7.2 on their machine if you target your app in .NET Framework 4.7.2.

**Notice that .NET 4.6 and greater version can only be installed on Windows 7 with SP1 and later Windows, you may have to know who will use your app and decide the right version of .NET Framework.**

Microsoft has introduced .NET Core 3 and support for Windows Desktop Applications
in Microsoft //Build/ 2018. So you will be able to target your WPF app in .NET Core 3 and there will be no need to install any other extra frameworks on their machines. That will happen in 2019, about one and a half year later.

You can read [.NET Core 3 and Support for Windows Desktop Applications | .NET Blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-3-and-support-for-windows-desktop-applications/) for more details. I link a key picture below.

> [image]
> <sub>(source: [windows.net](https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/2018/05/netcore3-1024x983.png))</sub>

Comment: And .net 4.5 and greater version cant install in XP.